# How to send email to official account from logged in user in django?

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to send email from the user who is logged in to an account which I have given `bilalkhangood4@gmail.com`. But I have typed it manually. There could be more accounts means more users `from` which I want to send. But how could I send email from just those users who are logged in? Basically it is an APP where a user will click on withdraw button to request and send mail to official admin account.

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'bilalkhangood4@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 587
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
def ViewSendEmail(request):
    send_mail('Hello from Bilal Khan',
        'Hello there, This is an automated message.',
        'bilalkhangood6@gmail.com', #FROM 
        ['bilalkhangood4@gmail.com'], #TO
        fail_silently=False)
    return render(request, 'nextone/email_send.html')
```

Comment: Anyone to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **request.user.email** to access the email address of logged in user.
update your code with following:

```
def ViewSendEmail(request):
    send_mail('Hello from Bilal Khan',
        'Hello there, This is an automated message.',
        request.user.email, #FROM 
        ['bilalkhangood6@gmail.com'], #TO
        fail_silently=False)
    return render(request, 'nextone/email_send.html')
```

Comment: Actually this should be done in opposite way. Means from will be ```request.user.email``` instead of ```bilalkhangood6@gmail.com```

Comment: Thank you! But I do have a problem. Whenever I receive an email, it shows me that I receive email from admin email address instead of user email. It should show me that it is received from user email address who are logged in.